# Github Classroom Autograding

Tags: java, github, junit5, github-classroom

I created an assignment in Github classroom and added test. The test is running when student commits and in actions tab shows passed or not.But in Github Classroom page as a teacher I cant see this.Doesn`t matter what I change I always get an "No test have been run".
Template file: [https://github.com/education/autograding-example-java\](https://github.com/education/autograding-example-java%5C)
Link for assignment:https://classroom.github.com/a/3vn_tHqL

How can I solve the problem so I can see where the student passed or not the test on Gihub Classroom page?